# How to simplify my Jquery codes

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make my codes less ugly. There are many if statement and repeating codes here. The main difference is insertBefore and prependTo alone with few css property changed. Are there any suggestions to simplify my codes here?? Thanks a million.

```
if($element.closest('div').hasClass('links')){
    $(document.createElement('img'))
        .attr({src:'inc/images/bubble_anim.gif',  'class': 'helpImg'})
        .insertBefore($element)
        .css({'position':'absolute',
            'z-index':99,
            'top': topPos+30,
            'left': leftPos
         })

     return true;
 }

 if($element.attr('id')=='option'){
     $(document.createElement('img'))
         .attr({src:'inc/images/bubble_anim.gif',  'class': 'helpImg'})
         .prependTo($element)
         .css({ 'z-index':99  })

     return true;
 }           

 //if the element is a td element, using propendTo method.
 if($element.is('td')){
     $(document.createElement('img'))
     .attr({src:'inc/images/bubble_anim.gif',  'class': 'helpImg'})
     .prependTo($element)
     .css({'position':'absolute',
         'z-index':99,
         'top': topPos,
         'left': leftPos
     })

     return true;
}

//regular elements...
$(document.createElement('img'))
    .attr({src:'inc/images/bubble_anim.gif',  'class': 'helpImg'})
    .insertBefore($element)
    .css({'position':'absolute',
        'z-index':99,
        'top': topPos,
        'left': leftPos
    })
```

Comment: Should your ifs be else ifs, or do you really need to evaluate each one, because that makes a big difference in whether this can be simplified?

Comment: I do need those return true statement...

Comment: Ah, right, my eyes glossed over the return true. Ok, so they CAN be else ifs then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var img = $("<img src='inc/images/bubble_anim.gif' class='helpImg'>");

var css = {'position':'absolute',
           'z-index':99,
           'top': topPos,
           'left': leftPos
};

if($element.attr('id')=='asmnt_option_label_q_count'){
    $img.prependTo($element).css({ 'z-index':99})
}
else if($element.is('td')){
    $img.prependTo($element).css(css);
}
else{      
    css.top += ($element.closest('div').hasClass('sub_links')) ? 30 : 0;         
    img.insertBefore($element).css(css)​;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it:

```
<style>
    .helpImg{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
    }   
</style>

var image = $("<img src='inc/images/bubble_anim.gif' class='helpImg'>");

if ($element.closest('div').hasClass('sub_links')) {

    image.css({
       'top': topPos+30,
       'left': leftPos
    }).insertBefore($element);

} else if ($element.attr('id')=='asmnt_option_label_q_count') {

    image.prependTo($element);          

} else {

    image.css({
        'top': topPos,
        'left': leftPos
    }).prependTo($element);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like :

```
$('<img />', {src: 'inc/images/bubble_anim.gif', 'class': 'helpImg'})
    [($element.attr('id')=='asmnt_option_label_q_count'||$element.is('td'))?'prependTo':'insertBefore']($element)
    .css({
        zIndex: 99,
        position: $element.attr('id')=='asmnt_option_label_q_count'?'static':'absolute',
        top: $element.closest('div').hasClass('sub_links')?topPos+30:$element.attr('id') == 'asmnt_option_label_q_count'?'':topPos,
        left: $element.attr('id') == 'asmnt_option_label_q_count'?'':leftPos
    });
​return true;
```